# WebApplication made using Struts keeps inserting null values to the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2

I'm working on a sample user-based java web application. When I try to add a user via registration to my database. After capturing the data on the front end, the records get stored as null values

i.e a row of my users table would contain the values (7, null, null, null, null) (using template id(primary-key), f_name, l_name, email, password).

Below are the files I believe could cause possible problems

User.java

```
package com.ysg.data;

import com.ysg.service.PasswordEncrypter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public User(){
        // default
    }

    public User( String password, boolean isEncrypted, String firstName, String 
    lastName, String email){
        this.password = isEncrypted ? password : encrypt(password);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }  //getters and setters follow
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.ysg.repository;

import com.ysg.data.User;
import com.ysg.exception.DuplicateItemException;
import com.ysg.exception.RepositoryException;
import com.ysg.util.MySQLHelper;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class UserRepository implements RepositoryInt<User> {
    private static final String INSERT = "INSERT INTO ysg.users (f_name, l_name, email, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private static final String USER_LOGIN = "SELECT * FROM ysg.users WHERE email=? and password=?";
    private static final String USER_FETCH = "SELECT * FROM ysg.users WHERE email='";
    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "f_name";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "l_name";
    private static final String EMAIL= "email";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    public UserRepository(){
        // default
    }

    @Override
    public User login(User obj){
        User result = find(obj);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override


    public User register(User obj){
        if (obj != null && (find(obj) == null)) {
            return add(obj);
        }
        return null;
    }



    private User add(User user){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT);
            stmt.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            stmt.setString(3, user.getEmail());
            stmt.setString(4, user.getPassword());
            stmt.execute();
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return user;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (ex.getMessage().contains("Duplicate")) {
                System.out.println("Item with duplicate id already exists in repository");
                throw new DuplicateItemException("Item with duplicate id already exists in repository");
            }
            else {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to add item to repository");
                throw new RepositoryException(ex);
            }
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    private User fetch(User user){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(USER_FETCH + user.getEmail()+ "'");
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            User result = marshall(resultSet);
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to fetch item from repository");
            throw new RepositoryException(ex);
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    private User find(User user){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(USER_LOGIN);
            stmt.setString(1, user.getEmail());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            User result = marshall(resultSet);
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to add item to repository");
            throw new RepositoryException(ex);
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    private User marshall(ResultSet result) throws RepositoryException, SQLException{
        if (result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        User user = null;
        if (result.next()) {
           // String id = result.getString(ID);
            String password = result.getString(PASSWORD);
            String firstName = result.getString(FIRSTNAME);
            String lastName = result.getString(LASTNAME);
            String email = result.getString(EMAIL);
            user = new User(password, true, firstName, lastName, email);
        }
        return user;
    }

    private Connection getConnection(){
        return MySQLHelper.getConnection();
    }

    private static void closeStatement(Statement stmt){
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
                //stmt = null;
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection(Connection conn){
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MySQLHelper.java

```
package com.ysg.util;

import com.ysg.data.User;
import com.ysg.exception.DuplicateItemException;
import com.ysg.exception.RepositoryException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class MySQLHelper {
    private static final String INSERT_USER = "INSERT INTO  users(f_name, l_name, email, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private static final String USER_FETCH = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='";
    private static final String FETCH_ALL = "SELECT * FROM users";
    private static final String COUNT_ALL_USERS = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
    private static final String DELETE_ALL = "DELETE FROM users";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "f_name";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "l_name";
    private static final String DS_NAME = "jdbc/sen301DS";
    private static Context envCtx;
    private static DataSource ds;

    static {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            System.out.println(envCtx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ConnectionPool will not be available - only direct connection can be used");
        }
    }

    public static List<User> fetch() throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(FETCH_ALL);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            List<User> result = marshall(resultSet);
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    public static User fetch(String id) throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(USER_FETCH + id + "'");
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            List<User> result = marshall(resultSet);
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return result.get(0);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    public static User add(User user){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER);
            stmt.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            stmt.setString(3, user.getEmail());
            stmt.setString(4, user.getPassword());
            stmt.execute();
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return user;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (ex.getMessage().contains("Duplicate")) {
                System.out.println("Item with duplicate id already exists in repository");
                throw new DuplicateItemException("Item with duplicate id already exists in repository");
            }
            else {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to add item to repository");
                throw new RepositoryException(ex);
            }
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    public static int countusers() throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(COUNT_ALL_USERS);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            int count = 0;
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                count = resultSet.getInt(1);
            }
            closeStatement(stmt);
            return count;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    public static void reset() throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(DELETE_ALL);
            closeStatement(stmt);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    private static List<User> marshall(ResultSet result) throws SQLException{
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        if (result == null) {
            return list;
        }
        while (result.next()) {
            String firstName = result.getString(FIRSTNAME);
            String lastName = result.getString(LASTNAME);
            String email = result.getString(EMAIL);
            String passwd = result.getString(PASSWORD);
            User user = new User(passwd, true, firstName, lastName, email);
            list.add(user);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static DataSource getDataSource(){
        DataSource ds = null;
        try {
            ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(DS_NAME);
        }
        catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RepositoryException("Failed to get DataSource");
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = getDataSource().getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RepositoryException("Failed to get connection to database server");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            con = getDirectConnection();
        }
        return con;
    }

    private static Connection getDirectConnection(){
        try {
            String conURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ysg?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&" + "user=sen301&password=sen301";
            return DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RepositoryException("Failed to get direct connection to database server");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RepositoryException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void closeStatement(Statement stmt){
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void closeConnection(Connection conn){
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the user object is properly populated before inserting?  Are you sure that values are being picked up correctly in the front end?

Comment: Yes I am. I have an action register that handles those 4 inputs (the ones I'm trying to capture in the database). It's also properly configured in my struts.xml.

Comment: have you added logging in your code to make sure?

Comment: Have you run a debugger to check if your object is really populated? Your DAO simply inserts entities into the database. The problem might happen long before on your controller. So, please post also your front-end logic.

Comment: Thank you very much turns out I was using old variable names in my key parameter in my struts form. So yes, it was a front end problem

Comment: User.java needs getter and setter for every field